# datalab Import Error: cannot import name 'vision'

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to call the Google Cloud Vision API from Google Cloud Datalab, but getting an import error. Has anyone encountered/resolved this?

I am following the guide in https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-safe-search

```
from google.cloud import vision
ImportError: cannot import name 'vision'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Datalab lists their [included libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/concepts/key-concepts#included_libraries). Datalab doesn't include google-cloud-vision by default.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/adding-libraries) are instructions for adding python libraries. You can pip install google-cloud-vision and then continue with the guide.

Comment: Yep. That did the trick for this particular hurdle. Thanks!

Now trying to resolve what seems to be compatibility errors between libraries.... it's odd to be stuck dealing with Google libraries in Google Datalab. If there are any books using vision in datalab, let me know!